# why this code runs i am boy 5 times when while condition is false

Tags: php

This code runs i am boy 5 times when while condition is false

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $a = 5;
    do {
        echo "I am boy.";
    } while ($a == $i);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in you question. What is the code supposed to do? What condition is false? What output do you see?

Comment: Do while always executes atleast 1 time, so FOR each time your FOR executes, the DO executes, which results in the behavour you are experiencing

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. Perhaps you were looking for a `while` instead of a `do while`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `do {...} while (...)` executes operations in `do` block first and than checks `while` condition if it should loop.

In your example it executes `echo` than checks that `$a` is not equal to `$i` so it doesn't loop and goes back to your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$a = 5;
echo "I am boy.";
$a == $i; // false 1 times

$i = 1;
$a = 5;
echo "I am boy.";
$a == $i; // false 2 times

$i = 2;
$a = 5;
echo "I am boy.";
$a == $i; // false 3 times

$i = 3;
$a = 5;
echo "I am boy.";
$a == $i; // false 4 times

$i = 4;
$a = 5;
echo "I am boy.";
$a == $i; // false 5 times
```

While condition is verified after the echo command. While `do while` execute code before the `while` condition, ... `while do` check exit condition before execution.